# How to design a database schema for multiple user types?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

## Question:

I have a system where I can have multiple types of users: buyers, vendors, admins, etc. These types of users aren't identical, but they're not utterly unlike each other.

There will be differences in both the attributes, behaviour, and privileges between them, having different life-cycles for them, and so on. But, they will also have some shared data and some shared behaviour, such as authentication. And I need it to be such that the users are mutually exclusive to each other.

I researched a few solutions other people had for how to represent this sort of data, but none of it seems like a silver bullet. They all seem to have some some down sides. Perhaps there isn't one.

## Approaches I found online

Here are some approaches I researched and know off, and why they have issues.

### Separate tables

So the simplest thing I can do is to just bite the bullet and have separate tables for each type of user. No linking to a super-table via foreign key constraints, or anything. This means I can evolve their behaviour more easily - I don't have to worry about needing a slightly different address logic between two types of users, I just build what I need. My schema becomes a little more self-explanatory - the foreign keys go to tables that say what they do.

Looking something like this:
[image]

But it is not entirely obvious to me how exactly I would deal with cross-cutting concerns for these different types. Such as a shared authentication mechanism.

I have this user auth token table:

[image]

But I'm not really sure WHICH of these users should I link to the foreign key of the authentication token? Since there isn't really a base table. There would have to be some unifying user super-table that is used for cross cutting concerns.

### Naive super-table

This seems to be the next step when brainstorming solutions to the problem. You have a base user table, and for each type of user, you have a separate table that links to the super-table via foreign key. For any type-specific behaviour, you link to the specific table, and for any cross-cutting concerns, such as authentication, you just link to the super-table.

It looks sort of like this:

[image]

It is relatively simple to understand, and works alright with cross cutting concerns. The problem is, this diagram seems to imply that a user can be both a buyer and a vendor, which is incorrect. Further more, it implies that I can create a user without it being a TYPE of user. I don't necessarily have to create a buyer or vendor when creating a user.

### Inheritance??

People also suggest to use PostgreSQL's table inheritence? But this just doesn't seem to solve, anything really. All it really does it provide an implicit `UNION` between super- and sub-tables when querying super-table, and the columns being shared don't even inherit the properties. So the PK `id` column would become just a regular `id` column.

If anyone knows how to get inheritance in Postgre to behave in polymorphic way (foreign key constraint for super-table satisfied by id values from sub-tables), let me know!!

### Inverting foreign key relations

To fix the implication that a user can be both a buyer and a vendor at the same time, I could flip the foreign keys relationship and have the super-table reference the sub-tables.

It looks like this:

[image]

But it also has a bit of extra syntax to enforce a few things, like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "user" (
    id               bigint       PRIMARY KEY,
    email_address    varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    phone_number     varchar(32)  NOT NULL,
    buyer_id         bigint       REFERENCES buyer(id),
    vendor_id        bigint       REFERENCES vendor(id),
    
    CHECK (
        buyer_id IS NOT NULL AND vendor_id IS     NULL OR
        buyer_id IS     NULL AND vendor_id IS NOT NULL
    )
);
```

But it also has issues. First of all, the more types of users, the more null values in the user table, reducing the data quality. For each type of user, the number of id references to those sub-tables would increase linearly, and the `CHECK` constraint statement would increase quadratically, to make sure only one of these is `NOT NULL`. The model now has the inverse issue of implying that a buyer or vendor can exist without the corresponding base user existing. Not ideal.

### Updatable views approach

Another way I found is to use updatable views to enforce the requirement that users cannot be both, buyers and vendors for example, and preventing the issue of a base user existing without being a user sub-type necessarily.

The diagram looks like this:

[image]

And the actual SQL for creating the tables is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "user" (
    id               bigserial    PRIMARY KEY,
    email_address    varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    phone_number     varchar(32)  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE buyer (
    id               bigint       PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name       varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    middle_name      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    last_name        varchar(255) NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES "user" (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE vendor (
    id               bigint       PRIMARY KEY,
    brand_name       varchar(255) NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES "user" (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

You would then create updatable views for these tables. These views would combine basically all the data for a user type, from both the super- and sub-tables, into one flat table. It would also be responsible for ensuring that buyers can't be vendors, and that both the super- and sub-table entries are created simultaneously.

In PostgreSQL, this is done with triggers, like so:

```sql
CREATE VIEW buyer_user AS
SELECT u.id,
       u.email_address,
       u.phone_number,
       b.first_name,
       b.middle_name,
       b.last_name
FROM "user" u
JOIN buyer b
ON u.id = b.id;

CREATE FUNCTION insert_into_buyer()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$BEGIN
    -- insert new user
    -- ignore NEW.id on insert
    INSERT INTO "user" (email_address, phone_number)
    VALUES (NEW.email_address, NEW.phone_number);

    -- insert new buyer
    -- using the same id as the new user
    INSERT INTO buyer (id, first_name, middle_name, last_name)
    VALUES(currval('user_id_seq'), NEW.first_name, NEW.middle_name, NEW.last_name);

    RETURN NULL;
END$$;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_into_buyer
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
    ON buyer_user
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_into_buyer();
```

This is only the code for handling inserts for buyer view. Other functions and triggers would have to be written to handle all the other operations and for other updatable views too. And then client code would essentially only use these updatable views, revoking permissions to the base table in production altogether.

But the downside to this approach is that you have to write a lot of custom functions and triggers to make everything work. And these trigger functions are more prone to error than simple table declarations in SQL. Secondly, this paradigm sort of commits you to using updatable views for everything, for the sake of consistency, and the base tables would be inaccessible to client code. Using views like that could be limiting in unforeseen ways. And you would have two different schemas, a virtual one and a base one. Super confusing.

### Entity-Attribute-Value

Another approach I've seen floating around, is, instead of having separate tables for the different types of users, have one user table that is used for cross-cutting concerns, and handle user-type-specific data through EAV.

It would look something like this

[image]

The upside is that you can do cross-cutting concerns with this approach, a user cannot be both a buyer and vendor, and a base user cannot exist without being some TYPE of user. All while being able to store data that is specific to a user type.

The downside is that, it is EAV, and EAV is an anti-pattern. So it comes with all the down sides of EAV such as no data validation, complex queries, no column indexing, poor performance. Furthermore, this specific design has the issue of being able to: for a user and user column who have different user roles respectively, you can still make a user data row. So you'd have to write client code or stored procedures or some other abstraction to block the recording of such erroneous data. Further more, it would be really weird to interact with this data model through an ORM like JPA.

## Summary

What I'm asking is, after reading all that: are there any OTHER ways that are better? Are there alterations to the options I already presented that would eliminate the negatives that I've highlighted?

Comment: There is no "best" in engineering until you define yours & then you need to give it & ask how you are stuck evaluating it or achieving it.

Comment: well i guess then its not best but, more approaches. I'm concerned that I might be missing something incredibly obvious and everyone else knows it but I dont

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please have your question ask what you want to ask, not what you don't want to ask. Design for subtypes/inheritance/polymophism is a faq here & at [so]. Also, just asking for generic approaches is frequently considered unfocused. [Why was my "shopping list" question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/266284) [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) [ask] [Help]